# Azure Batch Conversion of Video to Audio

Tags: c#, azure, ffmpeg, azure-functions, azure-media-services

I'm trying to build a function app that takes in a large amount of video files (potentially 1000s of hours) in blob storage and converts the video to audio and I'm running into some difficulty.

So far I've tried to use an uploaded version of ffmpeg embedded in an Azure function, and while this works for smaller individual videos, it continually fails when trying to scale to large videos (10s of GBs). The issue seems to be that the working set memory (found in Advanced tools) for the ffmpeg executable will not scale beyond ~20 MB, even though the function app storage will scale to whatever is necessary.

It seems like there are three options.

1. If there is a way to expand the ffmpeg maximum working set memory in my Azure function I could just do this and it would be an easy solution. I looked around and there was no clear instruction on how to expand the memory for an executable copied into an Azure function.
2. I could be using Azure functions incorrectly and this is a job better suited for another Azure service (such as Media Services or something that runs more in the background). I plan to upload videos in batches every week or so and I won't necessarily need them converted right away. There seems to be multiple ways to do what I intend to so it's possible that an experienced user would know of a better option.
3. I could cut the videos into sections that fit in the working set memory of ffmpeg, convert all sections, and then add code to merge back together at the end of the function. It seems like I would need media services to do this.

If anyone is more experienced in Azure and can point me in the right direction it'd be greatly appreciated.

Here's my current Azure function. It works on smaller videos but on larger videos it never exits the while loop since ffmpeg runs out of storage.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
 
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    string connectionString = "__";
    string containerNameIn = "__";
    string containerNameOut = "___";
    BlobContainerClient inContainer = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerNameIn);
    BlobContainerClient outContainer = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerNameOut);
    
    // List of video files in original container
    List<string> namesIn = new List<string>();
    foreach (BlobItem blob in inContainer.GetBlobs())
    {
        if (blob.Name[0] == 'S')
        {
            namesIn.Add(blob.Name.Substring(6, 29));
        }
    }

    // List of video files in Audio container
    List<string> namesOut = new List<string>();
    foreach (BlobItem blob in outContainer.GetBlobs())
    {
        namesOut.Add(blob.Name.Substring(0, 29));
    }

    //List of files to convert
    List<string> toConvert = new List<string>();
    List<string> converted = new List<string>();
    foreach (string name in namesIn)
    {
        if (!namesOut.Contains(name))
        {
            toConvert.Add(name);
        }
        else 
        {
            converted.Add(name);
        }
    }
    log.LogInformation("Num to Convert " + toConvert.Count().ToString());
    log.LogInformation("Num Converted " + converted.Count().ToString());

    //Get Blob List to Convert
    List<BlobItem> blobsToConvert = new List<BlobItem>();
    foreach (BlobItem blob in inContainer.GetBlobs()) 
    {
        if (blob.Name[0] == 'S') 
        {
            if (toConvert.Contains(blob.Name.Substring(6,29))) 
            {
                blobsToConvert.Add(blob);
            }
        }
    }
    log.LogInformation("Num ToDo Confirm " + blobsToConvert.Count().ToString());

    foreach (BlobItem blob in blobsToConvert)
    {
        var name = blob.Name;
        log.LogInformation("Name: "+name);
        BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(connectionString, "videos", name);
        name = name.Substring(6,29);
        var tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);
        var temp = name + ".avi";
        var temp2 = name + ".mp3";
        var tempIn = Path.Combine(tempPath, temp);
        var tempOut = Path.Combine(tempPath, temp2);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blobClient.DownloadTo(ms);
            File.WriteAllBytes(tempIn, ms.ToArray());
        } 
        var bs = File.ReadAllBytes(tempIn);
        log.LogInformation($"Length: {bs.Length}");
        try{
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = @"D:\home\site\wwwroot\ConvertAudioFormatUsingFFMpeg\ffmpeg.exe";
            psi.Arguments = $"-i \"{tempIn}\" -vn -ac 1 \"{tempOut}\"";
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            log.LogInformation("Starting");
            var process = Process.Start(psi);
            process.Refresh();
            while (!process.HasExited)
            {
                process.Refresh();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
                log.LogInformation("running");
            }
            log.LogInformation("Finished");
            log.LogInformation($"Output: {process.ExitCode}");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            log.LogInformation(ex.Message);
        }

        BlobClient outputClient = new BlobClient(connectionString, "audiotestfiles", temp2);
        outputClient.Upload(tempOut);
        File.Delete(tempIn);
        File.Delete(tempOut);
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide the code that you tried!

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT I just edited my post to include my current Azure function. Please note that the code does work on smaller videos but not on larger ones.

Comment: @gregl there is an example with your use case: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/batch-dotnet-ffmpeg-tutorial